# Visual state not changing when control invisible

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I've a button control that's got 2 visual states; say "Simple" and "Complex"; the former being the default. Initially the control is hidden.

When I set the visual state through *VisualStateManager* to "Complex", I get `false`, but when I make the control visible once and then set the visual state, it returns `true` and the state is preserved (even after the control becoming invisible) i.e. all that matters is if the control was shown atleast once; if so, the visual state changes are respected, else it's always ignored until it's shown once.

How do I set the visual state for a control that's yet to be visible?

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Background="LightBlue">
  <Grid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyButton"
           TargetType="Button">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
              <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MyStates">
                  <VisualState x:Name="Simple" />
                  <VisualState x:Name="Complex">
                    <Storyboard>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="10"
                                                Value="#00000000" />
                      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
              </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse"
                       Fill="#FF0E0EF5"
                       Stroke="Black" />
              <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Grid.Resources>
  <Button x:Name="btnStuff"
          Content="Click Me!"
          Visibility="Collapsed"
          Style="{StaticResource MyButton}" />
  <StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="btnShow"
            Content="Show"
            Click="btnShow_Click" />
    <Button x:Name="btnVisual"
            Content="Visual Change"
            Click="btnVisual_Click" />
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Code behind:**

```
    bool fOriginalState = true;

    private void btnShow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btnStuff.Visibility = btnStuff.Visibility == Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible ? Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed : Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void btnVisual_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string visualState = fOriginalState ? "Complex" : "Simple";
        fOriginalState = !fOriginalState;
        bool fSet = VisualStateManager.GoToState(btnStuff, visualState, false);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fSet.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: I think initially `btnStuff` is collapsed, so it's not rendered on page. Hence `VisualStateManager` can't find the button. Once you make it visible and then collapsed, it may become part of UI Element tree. I am not sure about this thing.

Comment: Do you set the initial state of your button in the ctor of your view?

Comment: @Jehof: No, I didn't but then in the XAML the visibility is set to collapsed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx)

> It is also appropriate to call the VisualStateManager.GoToState method
>   from a Loaded handler in order to set an initial view state that is
>   defined in the template.

under the `FrameworkElement.Loaded` event handler page; however, setting the required visual state here too gets ignored if `Visibility="Collapsed"` was hardcoded in the XAML.

The reason behind this issue is, when a control's `Visibility` was set to `Collapsed` right from the beginning of the app. then it never gets loaded; it's deferred until the property is set to `Visible` during runtime; once it's set, then it does get loaded, there by making the control appear in the VisualTree. Before appearing in the visual tree, any visual state change requests for a control gets neglected.

The work around I've found is to not set the control to `Collapsed` in XAML; since the control is visible, it gets loaded and in the loaded event handler, one can set the `Visibility` to `Collapsed`, all calls to VSM.GotoState would get honoured since the control is already in the VisualTree now.

Hope this helps someone who's fumbling around for a solution like me.